# Tomcat connection pool recover when database cannot be opened

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, spring-batch, connection-pooling

I have a Spring Batch job that executes some DAO jpa code using tomcat connection pool connection - the batch job runs once every 5 minutes.  My connection pool properties looks like

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public javax.sql.DataSource myDataSource() {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(myDriverClass);
    ds.setUrl(myUrl);
    ds.setUsername(myUsername);
    ds.setPassword(myPassword);
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    ds.setTestOnReturn(false);
    ds.setValidationInterval(3000);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(5000);
    ds.setMaxActive(100);
    ds.setInitialSize(10);
    ds.setMaxWait(90000);
    ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60000);
    ds.setMinIdle(10);
    //ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(300);
    //ds.setLogAbandoned(true);
    //ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    ds.setJdbcInterceptors(
        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
            //"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;"+
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
    ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [myDb].[dbo].[tbl_Reports]");
    return ds;
}
```

My DAO method looks like

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


@Override
public Long getLastVersion(String table_name) {
    ChangetableVersions ctv = null;
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM ChangetableVersions c WHERE c.tableName = :table_name");
        q.setParameter("table_name", table_name);
        ctv = (ChangetableVersions) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Long.valueOf(0);
    }
    return ctv.getLastVersion();

}
```

Most of the time this job runs fine.

But - this job runs every 5 minutes against a database that **every once in a while goes into single user mode while a SQL Server Agent job performs database restore**.  When the job happens to run while the database is in single user mode I get an exception

```
09:10:20.136 [INFO ] com.company.myagentmonitor.config.myAgentThreadPoolTaskScheduler -  Reports Job 1 done
09:13:32.727 [DEBUG] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection - Unable to validate object:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Database 'MYDB' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:903)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:796)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:769)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:443)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.testAllIdle(ConnectionPool.java:1076)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.run(ConnectionPool.java:1465)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How would I set up tomcat connection pool so that it recovers from this exception?  Right now my service errors out.  What I'd like to do is
have tomcat connection pool close the connection, and attempt to reconnect - if it can't reconnect, then wait 30 seconds to a minute until the database is available again, and then try to reconnect?

Thanks, any advice appreciated.

Comment: The connection pool is already setup to recover. If your job runs every 5 minutes, the next run (depending on how long database is unavailable, of course) will connect without problems and run normally. If you want *your job* to **retry** after 30 seconds, they *you* need to code that. Remember, the job may be half done when database goes down, so it's up to the job how it recovers from that. The connection pool cannot re-establish a killed connection, because everything done in the previous connection has been lost.

Comment: That error looks like it comes from tomcat connection pool doing connection validation and not from inside of the batch job, i'm not sure how to recover from that?

Comment: That error occurs in the background, when Tomcat is testing the connections in the pool. You code hasn't failed yet, so you don't have a problem (yet). If the database has completed the restore when the next job run, it'll run without error, using a new connection. Logged error doesn't indicate anything is wrong (yet).

Comment: Thank you, that clears up a lot of questions :)